# ActiveRecord: query attribute but ignore special characters and case

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Value` model, which has a `name` attribute. 
A few examples of what name could be:

```
value_1-example
Value2/Exampl-e
```

I'd like to be able to find the values having these names by searching a sanitized string:

`value1example` => returns the values having the name `value_1-example`

`value2example` => returns the values having the name `Value2/Exampl-e`

Basically, it is querying the database without taking into account special characters such as `/`, `_`, `-`, and making the query case insensitive.

Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `replace`

```
Model.where("replace(replace(LOWER(name), '_', ''), '-', '') like ?", '%value1example%')
```

The only thing is you have to use a replace for every character

If you are using Postgres you can make use of `regex_replace`